# Excel VBA - Merge specific columns from multiple files to one sheet

Tags: vba, file, excel

I have hundreds of excel files that I want to combine into one file.  The problem is that these files contain hundreds of columns of extra data that I do not need. Further complicating things is that the column positions differ between workbooks and workbooks have differing number of columns. I want to create a macro that will go through and open each file, search for the columns I need, and then copy those columns of data and combine them into one master file.

The way the below code works is as follows:
place all the files you want to combine into one folder
Type the headers you want to search for and combine within those files on a new workbook.

If you have 4 columns in your files named: Name Date Product and Time

Then typing Date and Time in A1 and B1 in a new worksheet will search all the files and combine any columns found with matching headers to a compilation sheet.

Thanks to Ron DeBruin for most of the filesystem selection.

```
    'Option Explicit

    'takes worksheet and returns last row
    Private Function LastRowUsed(sh As Worksheet) As Long
        On Error Resume Next
        LastRowUsed = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
    'takes worksheet and returns last column
    Private Function LastColUsed(sh As Worksheet) As Long
On Error Resume Next
LastColUsed = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function

    Function GetFileListArray() As String()
Dim fileDialogBox As FileDialog
Dim SelectedFolder As Variant
Dim MYPATH As String
Dim MYFILES() As String
Dim FILESINPATH
Dim FNUM, i As Integer

        '''''
        Set fileDialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

         'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
         With fileDialogBox
             If .Show = -1 Then 'the user chose a folder
         For Each SelectedFolder In .SelectedItems
            MYPATH = SelectedFolder 'asign mypath to the selected folder name
           ' MsgBox "The path is: " & SelectedFolder 'display folder selected
         Next SelectedFolder
         'The user pressed Cancel.
         Else
            MsgBox "Cancel was pressed or Invalid folder chosen, ending macro"
            Exit Function
         End If
         End With
         'Set the file dialog object variable to Nothing to clear memory
         Set fileDialogBox = Nothing
           If Right(MYPATH, 1) <> "\" Then
             MYPATH = MYPATH & "\"
           End If
        FILESINPATH = Dir(MYPATH & "*.csV")
        If FILESINPATH = "" Then
           MsgBox "No files found"
          Exit Function
        End If

        'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
        FNUM = 0
        Do While FILESINPATH <> ""
          FNUM = FNUM + 1
          ReDim Preserve MYFILES(1 To FNUM)
          MYFILES(FNUM) = FILESINPATH
          FILESINPATH = Dir()
        Loop


GetFileListArray = MYFILES()
End Function
    Sub RFSSearchThenCombine()
'search first worksheet in files opened, change to search other worksheets
Const SHEET_TO_SEARCH = 1

Dim FileList() As String
Dim CurrentFolder As String
Dim openedWorkBook As Workbook, HeadingWorkbook As Workbook
Dim OpenedWorkSheet As Worksheet, HeadingWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim i, counter, x As Integer
Dim LRowHeading, LRowOpenedBook, LColHeading, LColOpenedBook As Long
Dim dict As dictionary
Dim searchValue
'set original workbook with headings to retrieve
Set HeadingWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set HeadingWorkSheet = HeadingWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'find last column on heading worksheet
LColHeading = LastColUsed(HeadingWorkSheet)
'create dictionary to link headers to position in heading worksheet

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For x = 1 To LColHeading
        dict.Add HeadingWorkSheet.Cells(1, x).Value, x
    Next x

FileList() = GetFileListArray()

For counter = 1 To UBound(FileList)
    Set openedWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(CurrentFolder & FileList(counter))
    Set OpenedWorkSheet = openedWorkBook.Sheets(SHEET_TO_SEARCH)
    LColOpenedBook = LastColUsed(openedWorkBook.Sheets(1))
    LRowOpenedBook = LastRowUsed(openedWorkBook.Sheets(1))
    LRowHeading = LastRowUsed(HeadingWorkSheet)

           For i = 1 To LColOpenedBook 'search headers from a1 to last header
                searchValue = OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(1, i).Value 'set search value to current header
                If dict.Exists(searchValue) Then
                      OpenedWorkSheet.Range(OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(1, i), _
                      OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(LRowOpenedBook, i)).Copy _
                      (HeadingWorkSheet.Cells(LRowHeading, dict.Item(searchValue)))
                End If
            Next
        openedWorkBook.Close (False)
Next ' move on to next file

    End Sub
```

Comment: If the problem is as I understand (you manage to make the "master sheet" for each workbook but the ordering of the columns is messed up), you could try to do the following. Set a [Dictionary Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) to hold the name of the header and it's position, then refer to this dictionary when "importing" to your compilation sheet one column at a time. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  However I do not want to import all the columns, just the ones I need.  There is over 250 columns on most workbooks and I only use about 20 of them.  That is why I was thinking searching for the headers that I want, then storing the locations in an array.  I suppose I could use a dictionary object instead of two arrays, but either way its a significant change from the original vanilla "master sheet" macro

Comment: Exactly. One way to do it, is to set the Dictionary to hold the positions at which you want specific headers. Then go through each column of each file to determine whether or not to import (by referring to Dictionary), and if so, where to! I like your `LastRowUsed` and `LastColUsed` functions, they're much neater than the whole `worksheet.cells(worksheet.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row` blotter. Plus they don't rely on one specific column... Mind if I grab that off you? :)

Comment: lol, sure go ahead.  I probably grabbed them from else where myself when I first started using them.   Could you give me a code example using dictionary for that purpose?  I've only used a dictionary object once...and that was almost a year ago :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you'd use a dictionary to store the name and column number of the columns of interest (based on an arbitrarily named "COMPILATION SHEET"). *Remember you need to enable the reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".*

```
Sub InitiateDictionary()
Dim d As Dictionary
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("COMPILATION SHEET")

lastCol = LastColUsed(ws)
For x = 1 To lastCol
    d.Add ws.Cells(1, x), x
Next x
End Sub


Private Function LastColUsed(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastColUsed = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

All you need to do is elaborate a way to know if an element is contained by the dictionary (define the function `DContains(dictionary, string)`). There are examples on Google on how to do that. Once you know that the header is inside the dictionary, you can use that header name to know the column number it refers to. A bit like this :

```
colNumber = 0
headerToFind = "Header_A"
found = DContains(d, headerToFind)
if found then
    colNumber = d(headerToFind)
end if
if colNumber > 0 then
    'Perform copy to column "colNumber" !
end if
```

---

To determine how many entries are in the dictionary, simply use the `.Count` property.

And yes, in this case `Cells(x,1)` is the same as `Cells(x,1).value`.

Comment: Ok, I was confusing dictionary with an item map I think.  When you do d.add ws.cell(1,x),x does it add the cell.value to it?  Or the cell range?  Or does it not matter?

Comment: Another question I have is if it is necessary to resize the range if I store the entire columns?

Comment: A dictionary is the same as an item map (not exactly sure what an ITEM map is, but a map is a dictionary). When you do `d.add ws.cells(1,x), x`, you add the value of the cell in the first row in column x (as a key), and the value of the x (as the value), to the dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "necessary to resize the range if I store entire columns".

Comment: I think I understand what you mean... What the `InitiateDictionary()` sub actually does is look at the headers you have in place in your "COMPILATION SHEET" (which is where all worksheets merge to), and remember where you positioned each header. You then use the macro you had in place to go through each workbook and treat columns according to their header.

Comment: Hey thanks for all the help, been out of office but now im back and working on the problem... How do I determine how many entries are in the dictionary?  Also I changed d.add Cells(x,1), x to d.add Cells(x,1).value, x   That shouldnt create any problems correct?