# Merge specific cells from columns from multiple files to one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to merge data from particular columns from multiple csv files. This thread: [Excel VBA - Merge specific columns from multiple files to one sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219350/excel-vba-merge-specific-columns-from-multiple-files-to-one-sheet) worked for whole ranges of columns. However, I want to copy e.g. each 100th cell from particular column (instead of whole column as it is at the moment).

I have tried to modify the code as per below method 1 and 2 (see **** notes).

This VBA is to go through datalog files which have time stamps in rows and parameters for each time stamp. However, I don't want all parameters, only selected ones (per columns) and in each 100th row.

```
'takes worksheet and returns last row
Private Function LastRowUsed(sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRowUsed = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
     On Error GoTo 0
 End Function


'takes worksheet and returns last column
Private Function LastColUsed(sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastColUsed = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=sh.Range(A1), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


'takes worksheet and returns last row in column
Private Function LastRowUsedbyCol(sh As Worksheet, ByVal Col As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRowUsed = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=sh.Range(Cell(Col, 1), Cell(Col, 1)), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function



Function GetFileListArray() As String()
    Dim fileDialogBox As FileDialog
    Dim SelectedFolder As Variant
    Dim MYPATH As String
    Dim MYFILES() As String
    Dim FILESINPATH
    Dim FNUM, i As Integer
    '''''
    Set fileDialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
    With fileDialogBox
        If .Show = -1 Then 'the user chose a folder
            For Each SelectedFolder In .SelectedItems
                MYPATH = SelectedFolder 'asign mypath to the selected folder name
                'MsgBox "The path is:" & SelectedFolder, vbInformation 'display folder selected
            Next SelectedFolder
        'The user pressed Cancel.
        Else
            MsgBox "Cancel was pressed or Invalid folder chosen, ending macro"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
    'Set the file dialog object variable to Nothing to clear memory
    Set fileDialogBox = Nothing
    If Right(MYPATH, 1) <> "\" Then
        MYPATH = MYPATH & "\"
    End If
    FILESINPATH = Dir(MYPATH & "*.csv")
    'MsgBox FILESINPATH
    If FILESINPATH = "" Then
         MsgBox "No files found"
         Exit Function
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    FNUM = 0
    Do While FILESINPATH <> ""
        FNUM = FNUM + 1
        ReDim Preserve MYFILES(1 To FNUM)
        MYFILES(FNUM) = MYPATH & FILESINPATH
        FILESINPATH = Dir()
    Loop

    GetFileListArray = MYFILES()
End Function



Sub RFSSearchThenCombine()
'search first worksheet in files opened, change to search other worksheets
Const SHEET_TO_SEARCH = 1

Dim FileList() As String
Dim CurrentFolder As String
Dim openedWorkBook As Workbook, HeadingWorkbook As Workbook
Dim OpenedWorkSheet As Worksheet, HeadingWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim i, counter, x, j As Integer
Dim LRowHeading, LRowOpenedBook, LColHeading, LColOpenedBook, LRowHeadingC As Long
Dim dict As dictionary
Dim searchValue
'set original workbook with headings to retrieve
Set HeadingWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set HeadingWorkSheet = HeadingWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'find last column on heading worksheet
LColHeading = LastColUsed(HeadingWorkSheet)

'create dictionary to link headers to position in heading worksheet

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For x = 1 To LColHeading
    dict.Add HeadingWorkSheet.Cells(1, x).Value, x
Next x

FileList() = GetFileListArray()

For counter = 1 To UBound(FileList)
    Set openedWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(FileList(counter))
    Set OpenedWorkSheet = openedWorkBook.Sheets(SHEET_TO_SEARCH)
    LColOpenedBook = LastColUsed(openedWorkBook.Sheets(1))
    LRowOpenedBook = LastRowUsed(openedWorkBook.Sheets(1))
    LRowHeading = LastRowUsed(HeadingWorkSheet)

    For i = 1 To LColOpenedBook 'search headers from a1 to last header
        searchValue = OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(1, i).Value 'set search value in to current header
        If dict.Exists(searchValue) Then

            ' *** code from previous thread
            'OpenedWorkSheet.Range(OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(1, i), _
            'OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(LRowOpenedBook, i)).Copy _
            '(HeadingWorkSheet.Cells(LRowHeading, dict.Item(searchValue)))

            '**** my proposal
            For j = 1 To LRowOpenedBook Step 100
                OpenedWorkSheet.Range(OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(j, i), _
                OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(j, i)).Copy _
                (HeadingWorkSheet.Cells(LRowHeading + 1, dict.Item(searchValue)))
                LRowHeading = LRowHeading + 1

            '**** my 2nd  proposal
            'LRowHeadingC = HeadingWorkSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            'For j = 1 To LRowOpenedBook Step 100
                ' OpenedWorkSheet.Range(OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(j, i), _
                'OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(j, i)).Copy _
                '(HeadingWorkSheet.Cells(LRowHeadingC + 1, dict.Item(searchValue)))
                'LRowHeadingC = LRowHeadingC + 1

            Next j

        End If
    Next i
    openedWorkBook.Close (False)
Next counter ' move on to next file

End Sub
```

1st method (when working) results in shift of rows from next columns (all pasted data start from last row (not last row in particular column), it more less results in below pattern (where cl is for column and x represents data):

```
cl1  cl2  cl3  cl3
x
x
x     
      x
      x
      x    
           x
           x
           x     x
                 x
                 x

x
x
x
```

While I want to receive below pattern:

```
cl1  cl2  cl3  cl3
x    x    x    x
x    x    x    x
x    x    x    x
```

Another question is how should I modify function: LastRowUsed not to start from A1, but e.g. from B1, etc.? I tried to resolve that with Method 2.

Comment: How didn't `... Step 100` not work? Is there an error, is it missing some information/skipping info?

Comment: Basically no data is pasted into the HeadingWorkSheet

Comment: Does `dict.Item(searchValue)` return a number? Also, you're copying a range, so try pasting into a range too (instead of a range pasting to a cell) to see if that helps.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module - does your code still compile?  Your `LastRowUsedbyCol` has a couple of problems.

Comment: Reverse the nesting of your `i` and `j` loops - your top-level loop should loop over the rows, and the inner loop should loop over the columns in each row.  Increment `LRowHeading` in the outer loop, not the inner one (otherwise you're moving down one row for every value found)

Comment: @TimWilliams Reverse of the nesting worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback above I have changed the loops order and that made it work. I have also polished the code (copying from range to range and added option explicit). Code does the job now.

Now I will be trying to change it to more efficient version (it takes plenty of time with few hundreds of workbooks). At the moment I am copying and pasting each cell individually between workbooks. I think that a set of cells (e.g. multiple selection of each 100th cell) would be quicker.
Or building an array of values needed and pasting array into headingsWorkbook as range.

Here is how the code looks now:

```
    Option Explicit

   'takes worksheet and returns last row
    Private Function LastRowUsed(sh As Worksheet) As Long
        On Error Resume Next
        LastRowUsed = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function


    'takes worksheet and returns last column
    Private Function LastColUsed(sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastColUsed = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range(A1), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function


        'takes worksheet and returns last row in column
    Private Function LastRowUsedbyCol(sh As Worksheet, ByVal Col As String) As Long
        On Error Resume Next
        LastRowUsed = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range(Cell(Col, 1), Cell(Col, 1)), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function



Function GetFileListArray() As String()
    Dim fileDialogBox As FileDialog
    Dim SelectedFolder As Variant
    Dim MYPATH As String
    Dim MYFILES() As String
    Dim FILESINPATH
    Dim FNUM, i As Integer
        '''''
        Set fileDialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

         'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
         With fileDialogBox
            If .Show = -1 Then 'the user chose a folder
            For Each SelectedFolder In .SelectedItems
               MYPATH = SelectedFolder 'asign mypath to the selected folder name
               'MsgBox "The path is:" & SelectedFolder, vbInformation 'display folder selected
            Next SelectedFolder
            'The user pressed Cancel.
            Else
            MsgBox "Cancel was pressed or Invalid folder chosen, ending macro"
            Exit Function
            End If
         End With
         'Set the file dialog object variable to Nothing to clear memory
         Set fileDialogBox = Nothing
           If Right(MYPATH, 1) <> "\" Then
             MYPATH = MYPATH & "\"
           End If
        FILESINPATH = Dir(MYPATH & "*.csv")
        'MsgBox FILESINPATH
        If FILESINPATH = "" Then
           MsgBox "No files found"
          Exit Function
        End If

        'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
        FNUM = 0
        Do While FILESINPATH <> ""
          FNUM = FNUM + 1
          ReDim Preserve MYFILES(1 To FNUM)
          MYFILES(FNUM) = MYPATH & FILESINPATH
          FILESINPATH = Dir()
        Loop

GetFileListArray = MYFILES()
End Function

Sub RFSSearchThenCombineEach1000thRow()
'search first worksheet in files opened, change to search other worksheets
Const SHEET_TO_SEARCH = 1

Dim FileList() As String
Dim CurrentFolder As String
Dim openedWorkBook As Workbook, HeadingWorkbook As Workbook
Dim OpenedWorkSheet As Worksheet, HeadingWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim i, counter, x, j As Integer
Dim LRowHeading, LRowOpenedBook, LColHeading, LColOpenedBook As Long
Dim dict As dictionary
Dim searchValue
'set original workbook with headings to retrieve
Set HeadingWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set HeadingWorkSheet = HeadingWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'find last column on heading worksheet
LColHeading = LastColUsed(HeadingWorkSheet)
'create dictionary to link headers to position in heading worksheet

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For x = 1 To LColHeading
        dict.Add HeadingWorkSheet.Cells(1, x).Value, x
    Next x

FileList() = GetFileListArray()

For counter = 1 To UBound(FileList)
    Set openedWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(FileList(counter))
    Set OpenedWorkSheet = openedWorkBook.Sheets(SHEET_TO_SEARCH)
    LColOpenedBook = LastColUsed(openedWorkBook.Sheets(1))
    LRowOpenedBook = LastRowUsed(openedWorkBook.Sheets(1))
    LRowHeading = LastRowUsed(HeadingWorkSheet)

        For j = 2 To LRowOpenedBook Step 1000
            LRowHeading = LRowHeading + 1 'move one row down in HeadingWorkbook, each 1000 rows of openedworkbook

                For i = 1 To LColOpenedBook 'search headers from a1 to last header
                     searchValue = OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(1, i).Value 'set search value in to current header
                     If dict.Exists(searchValue) Then

                             OpenedWorkSheet.Range(OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(j, i), _
                             OpenedWorkSheet.Cells(j, i)).Copy _
                             HeadingWorkSheet.Range(HeadingWorkSheet.Cells(LRowHeading, dict.Item(searchValue)), _
                             HeadingWorkSheet.Cells(LRowHeading, dict.Item(searchValue)))

                     End If
                 Next i

        Next j
        openedWorkBook.Close (False)
Next ' move on to next file

    End Sub
```